# Invalid entry CRC in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hello so today I planned to do some work but now, all my projects are --- I dont know what happened, the same errors occurs in intellij, vscode. Can someone guide me what is wrong?

```
022-03-31 17:25:35.542 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar]

java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x33d53c29 but got 0xadb3fec8)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:409) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:194) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readNBytes(InputStream.java:409) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes(InputStream.java:346) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarInputStream.checkManifest(JarInputStream.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:61) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.getManifest(ExtensionValidator.java:321) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.addSystemResource(ExtensionValidator.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.<clinit>(ExtensionValidator.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5044) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:478) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.what.WhatApplication.main(WhatApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
```

The same errors with the following jars

```
2022-03-31 17:25:35.550 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.5.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar]
2022-03-31 17:25:35.553 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.2.2/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar]
2022-03-31 17:25:35.565 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.2/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar]
2022-03-31 17:25:35.568 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.2.jar]
2022-03-31 17:25:35.571 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.2.jar]
2022-03-31 17:25:35.576 ERROR 8097 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator     : Failure loading extension [/home/killme/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.200/h2-1.4.200.jar]
```

Cleaned /home,cache, etc, reinstalled intellij, tried with vscode, tried with reactive spring.

Comment: Please add some information about your project.  Are you using, maven or gradle.  JDK Version.

Comment: I've tried with Maven/Gradle, using OpenJDK 17/11 from Archlinux, using Temurin 17.02 from AUR. Reinstalled the entire OS and the problem is still there. I really dont know what is happening.

Comment: Try cleaning `/home/killme/.m2/` folder and rebuild the project afterwards.

Comment: I LITERALLY reinstalled the entire OS. Then tried with a simple hello world on spring boot v2.6.6/2.5.12. With Intellij, Vscode. deleted all caches, configs, etc. But nothing works.

Comment: Share your project on Github so we can clone it and test it.

Comment: Its a simple default spring boot web app

start.spring.io -> dependency: web

Just that, nothing like controllers, services, etc. Just a simple web app from start.spring.io.
Maybe you could get this error if you delete your m2 (backup m2 first), and then open the spring boot project from start.spring.io.

I've deleted all caches, config, reinstalled the entire OS, etc. 

I just don't know what else can I do, it's sad at this point.

Comment: When i look at tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar with 7zip it says "WARNINGS:
Headers Error", but then I go to [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.60](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.60) check the sha's and all of them are the same from maven. I really dont know what is happening. Gradle gives me the same error. As I said before my system is Archlinux with java default set to jdk-11

Comment: I'm hitting a very similar Exception on my project. We have a springBoot packaged fat jar deployed in k8s cluster. The assembled app works fine on my local machine (macos), but does not start when it is deployed in the cluster (jre17-alpine). In my case it is a liquibase loader scanning for resources. If I disable the liquibase the app starts fine.

Comment: the interesting thing - it started randomly, without any major code modifications which could explain the issue (all the dependencies versions were same).  Unpacking the fat jar and running a simple unzip command check was OK for all of the jars.

Comment: I opened a github issue and they didn't even care about it lol [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30532](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30532).
I found another random dude on twitter that has the same issue, it started after he deleted the m2 folder. They say that is a maven problem from my side but I haven't change anything in my network, I checked my router for logs and I didn't find anything that is interfering with maven. It started when 2.6.6 was released and I deleted the m2 folder.

Comment: I had this with springboot 2.5.6. updated to 2.6.6 with no effect.

Comment: Do you have an option to debug the problem? Start the JVM in debug mode and create an Exception breakpoint? That will localize the problem down to concrete jar file. It's difficult to do same thing in my setup

Comment: Hi, I can not recreate the problem.  I generated a new project from https://start.spring.io/. 
 Spring 2.6.6, web dependency and nothing else. The project starts correctly.  I use Linux mint, maven and Jdk15. Please share your project on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing a similar error when I am building a Spring Boot project in Arch Linux

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.6:repackage (repackage) on project unespfc-servicedesk: invalid entry CRC (expected 0x6be9f308 but got 0x7dfa3146)
```

After I downgrade zlib package, the error is gone.

```
sudo pacman -U https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/z/zlib/zlib-1%3A1.2.11-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

I have opened a bug report for this https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/74371

Comment: But I just don't understand how can it works with jdk11 and with the jdk17 it fails. I did downgrade it (zlib) and the error was gone but we are just hiding the bug (downgrading the package ?). It tilts me that with jdk11 works fine (even with the new zlib) but with jdk17 doesn't.

Comment: In my tests it is not related with JDK version, even jdk11 fails with the new zlib version. I can not understand why in some CPU it not occurs. See again the bug report in Arch Linux. There are more comments about CPU models working and not working. I asked the zlib developer about it. More info [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/issues/618).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing @Demitrius Belai did. I think is is a zlib bug in some processors.

I run a spring-boot project on temurin:17-alpine docker image. But the bug only happens on server machine.

I inpect this docker image and it use new zlib version 1.2.12. I does not know downgrade this zlib version.

But ai change docker image to ubuntu version (temurin:17). And this image use older version 1.2.11. And it worked!

Thanks,